# Weeks in month adjustment in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have salesdate for whole last year (01/01/2012 to 12/31/2012). I want to create 
a week variable in such a way that there are only 4 weeks consistent over the months.

In other words, I want

```
01/01/2012-01/07/2012  = week1
01/08/2012-01/14/2012  = week2
01/15/2012-01/21/2012  = week3
01/22/2012-01/31/2012  = week4
```

(I can not use ww. format because my week 4 does not fit the  always definition of week 4 in Oracle SQL Developer.)

I am wondering if anybody can help me on this.

Answer (score 3):

Try this expression:

```
select LEAST(TRUNC((EXTRACT(day FROM salesdate) + 6) / 7), 4) week
FROM salesdata;
```

Note:

- `EXTRACT` extracts the day from the date
- `TRUNC( (x + 6) / 7)` divides it by seven days and truncates it to an integer number
- `LEAST( x, 4 )` limits it to a maximum of 4

Answer (score 1):

Well your last week has 9 days, so that is kind of weird...

but you could try something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_WEIRD_WEEK(I_DATE DATE) 
 RETURN NUMBER AS
BEGIN
  RETURN CASE
           WHEN FLOOR(TO_CHAR(I_DATE,'DD')/7)+1 > 3
             THEN 4
             ELSE FLOOR(TO_CHAR(I_DATE,'DD')/7)+1
         END;
END;
```

otherwise i would suggest you distribute the days evenly across the month's quarters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_WEIRD_WEEK(I_DATE DATE) RETURN NUMBER AS
BEGIN
  RETURN FLOOR(TO_CHAR(I_DATE,'DD')/TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(I_DATE),'DD')*4)+1;
END;
```